# How do I connect up my Amazon EC2 instances without manually modifying config files?

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2

I have a three-tier Windows-based web application bundled into 3 AMIs on Amazon EC2 that I use for load testing.

- An ASP.NET web application on IIS
- An .NET application server
- SQL Server

After I launch them, the config files of each tier needs modifying to update the IP addresses.

At the moment I am doing this manually: I connect to the webserver instance via remote desktop and modify the config file to point to the new IP of the application server instance.  Then I do the same with the application server to change the IP in the connection string.

This must be a common requirement and I must be missing something obvious.  There must be a better way!

- I could use Elastic IP addresses, but these machines are only provisioned for a couple of hours at a time, and I would be charged for the addresses when they were NOT in use (which would be most of the time).
- Is there some way of persistently naming the machines?  Can I somehow get all the machines on the same network and use machine names instead of IP addresses?
- I could write some nifty PowerShell script that would perform the modifications remotely. Is there an example somewhere?
- I could use a [dynamic IP address service](http://dnslookup.me/dynamic-dns/). I'm not sure if this would have any negative effect on performance or availability... Are there any downsides to this approach?
- I could install some sort of self-configuring service on each machine (which connects to S3? SNS? SimpleDB?) to publish/retrieve the addresses of the other machines and update the config files automatically.  Is there an example somewhere?

What is best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC)](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/). You have a private subnet where you can [assign an IP address to an instance](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/#I13), but it may require [launching an instance from command line to assign IP](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=66253). VPC is charged the same way as EC2.